# Calling constructors for element objects in the constructor of a parent class

Tags: c++, constructor, parent-child

QUESTION UPDATED:

I want to do the following in C++:

```
struct Param {
public:
    int len;
    int in1;
    float in2;
};

Param params;

class Element {
private:
    int value1;
    float value2;
public:
    Element();
    Element(int n) {value1 = n; value2 = 0;}
    Element(int n1, float n2) {value1 = n1; value2 = n2;}
}

class Parent {
private:
    class Element elem;
    vector<Element> elemVec;
public:
    Parent();
    Parent(int n);
}
```

I wish to write the following constructor such that on calling `Parent` constructor, the non-default constructors for class elements `elem` and `elemVec` also gets called. I have figured out that the constructor for `elem` needs to be called as follows:

```
Parent::Parent(int n) : elem(n) {

}
```

How do I now construct each element of `elemVec` vector, such that `Element(int, float)` constructor gets called for each vector element with `int` and `float` values picked up from the struct fields `params.value1` and `params.value2`. The size of `elemVec` needs to be defined by the struct field `params.len`.

Writing a loop in the constructor body gives unwanted behaviour of the constructed objects.

Comment: I need a general solution. The input `numVec` given to the constructor need not be a vector of ints, and may not even be a vector. I used this case just as an example.

Comment: Can you list the possible types that `numVec` can be?

Answer (score 5):

The following implementation should work. However, it depends on the implicit conversion from `int` to `Element`, and is not a general solution.

```
Parent::Parent(int n, const vector<int> &numVec)
    : elem(n),
      elemVec(numVec.begin(), numVec.end())
{ }
```

Comment: I need a general solution. The input given to the constructor `numVec` need not be a vector of ints, and may not even be a vector.

Comment: @vikaspraj: Then please update your question with the **actual** requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This solution does what you want:

```
Parent::Parent(int n, const vector<int>& numVec)
    : elem(n)
{
    elemVec.reserve(numVec.size());
    for (auto num : numVec)
        elemVec.emplace_back(num);
}
```

A default construction of an empty vector is basically free.

The reserve allocates the full memory block needed as a vector(n) constructor would.

emplace_back constructs the items in place as efficiently as is possible.

Comment: Why not `const vector<int> &numVec`? In this way the `vector` will be copied 3 times.

Comment: copy and paste typo fixed - however I don't know where you got 3 times from?  The vector would be copied once, after the fix zero times. (or if you are counting numVec->elemVec as a copy, than twice and now once)

Comment: Ok, yes. I just copied the text, too. :)